# How to set-up SQL Server / IIS 7.0 to allow ASP.NET MVC website to access to database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have built an ASP.NET MVC 2 website that I am hosting with Rackspace Cloud Server using IIS 7.0.

When I try to test the website under localhost with IIS 7.0 on the server I get an error page. This comes from the SQL logs (I am using SQL Web Edition):

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

My website works fine on my home PC so the issue is something to do with connecting with the database.

Having researched the error message code it suggests that I have a valid DB login but server access has failed. I did a stack of reading around this on various forums (incl. stackoverflow / serverfault) and here is what I have tried, none of which have solved the issue:

1. **Set up new login using SQL Server Authentication**. I created a new login in SQL and gave correct access rights to my DB. I used following connection string in web config:

   Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
2. **Create new login as `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`**. I created new login in SQL with correct access rights and used windows authentication. Connection string as follows:

   Server=myServer;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
3. **Use existing network login `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`**. I mapped this user to my database with correct access rights. Connection string as follows:

   Server=myServer;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

These appeard to be the main options as I read through material online. Finally, here as some other things that may be helpful:

- Setting SQL to **run as administrator** did not solve the issue
- Turning off `UAC` did not help
- My application pool is using **ApplicationPoolIdentity** (best for security reasons)

In short, my website won't start because it cannot get an object from the DB so throws an error. The issue is that access rights to the server are not set correctly. I cannot work out what configuration of SQL login / connection string / domain access rights I need.

This has vexed me for 3 weeks - can you spare 5 mins to help me please?

Comment: Can you post your current connection string? I assume you are connecting with Integrated Security, therefore the AppPoolIdentity is used to connect to SQL Server. Also, please mention if your web and sql servers are running in an Active Directory setup.

Comment: Using: `Source=SetsOfSix; Initial Catalog=SetsOfSix; Integrated Security=SSPI;`. Let me go check question on active directory setup...

Comment: On IIS `Active Directory Domain Services` is not installed. How would I check if web and sql servers are running in Active Directoty setup?

Comment: The simplest way is to go to computer properties and under the "Computer name, domain and workgroup settings" see if a `Domain` or `Workgroup` name is listed. I'm asking because depending on this there are two different options that can be applied (either use a domain user to connect to SQL, either use SQL authentication).

Comment: I have: `Computer Name = SETSOFSIX; Full Computer Name = SETSOFSIX; Workgroup = Workgroup;`

Comment: OK, so you're not running on a domain. I'm adding an answer below.

Comment: Great. Would it be better to run on a domain? I recall reading that using SQL authentication is less secure? Happy to go the domain route if it is better...

Comment: Not necessarily and depends entirely on your infrastructure needs. With more servers (over 3 I'd say) then you're better off running in a domain. But for that you need to make some preparations, establish some security scenarios and a separate domain controller machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your servers (web and SQL) are not part of a domain, you can't use Windows Authentication (Integrated Security) to connect to SQL Server.

In IIS, when having `Integrated Security=SSPI` in a connection string, the actual user used to connect to SQL Server is the application pool identity.

You should go with your option 1, meaning **Set up new login using SQL Server Authentication**.

So, the steps would be:

1. Create your `myUsername` SQL Server user.
2. In the user's properties dialog, go to the `Securables` section and make sure `Public` is checked.
3. Next, move to the `User mapping` section (in the left side). Look for your database(s) in the list and check it. Down below, in the `Database role membership` list, make sure you check `public`, `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter`.
4. Now give your user rights to execute stored procedures. As `sa`, in Management Studio, execute:

   GRANT EXECUTE TO myUserName;
5. You're done.

As for security, you can later refine the rights of `myUserName` to not be able, for example to drop tables or other objects.

In your application you should use now the connection string at your point 1.

If you have any other problems, then please post the error message.

Comment: Thanks. The bit I was missing was (a) setting `GRANT EXECUTE` and (b) in my LINQ-to-SQL I had an incorrect connection string reference. Fixing both solved issue. Your help got me looking in the right place.