# Create a web application run in a local computer with .NET and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I create a web application that have database and complex logic using MVC and .NET but run locally in a computer without network access or internet.

I want the application behave as a regular desktop application but using the browsers.

I know that I have just publish the application on localhost it will work but I want create a package that do it and I don't know I should start doing it or looking from documentation.

Comment: you have to enable IIS on that machine, or start the app from visual studio using the development web servers.

Comment: Yes, what ps2goat said, plus read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175858/how-to-set-up-sql-server-iis-7-0-to-allow-asp-net-mvc-website-to-access-to-dat

Comment: What do you mean by 'behave as a regular desktop application' ?

Comment: That the application run locally without need to be published in a server or only in a local server. Microsoft Robotic Studio MRS has an example of the application that I meant. After install MRS if you run a command 'dsshost -p:50000 -t:50000' it published the application for you and it have the services running with some database. Users use the browser to access the application the application is just locally deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or instead of IIS you can use WCF (or IIS Hostable Core) to run services from within your own program.  Also Cassini web server can accomplish similar (if that project still alive.

Comment: IIS Hostable Core looks like can solve the problem after read its documentation.